# Setting up admin views with Ember Simple Auth in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm using Ember Simple Auth and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to get the current user that is logged in and then checking if the user is an admin so I can display admin only thinks in templates. Currently I am using jwt authentication using Ember Simple Auth Token and a Ruby on Rails backend. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be great.

I've currently tried getting the example on the Ember Simple Auth to work
https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/guides/managing-current-user.md

When the user authenticates the jwt is returning the token and the user_id. The issue is that I'm not getting the name or any details about the user when the user is logged in.

I'm trying to access the current user (Which might be wrong) by doing this

```
{{currentUser.user.name}}
```

controller/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { inject: { service }, Component } = Ember;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session:     service('session'),
  currentUser: service('current-user')
});
```

routes/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  currentUser: service(),

  beforeModel() {
    return this._loadCurrentUser();
  },

  sessionAuthenticated() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this._loadCurrentUser().catch(() => this.get('session').invalidate());
  },

  _loadCurrentUser() {
    return this.get('currentUser').load();
  }
});
```

services/current-user.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { inject: { service }, isEmpty, RSVP } = Ember;

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  session: service('session'),
  store: service(),

  load() {
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let userId = this.get('session.data.authenticated.user_id');
      if (!isEmpty(userId)) {
        return this.get('store').find('user', userId).then((user) => {
          this.set('user', user);
        }, reject);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The ESA documentation is rich. What did you try and what is the problem?

Comment: I've update the post with the example that I used and the current code that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `findRecord`

```
load() {
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let userId = this.get('session.data.authenticated.user_id');
      if (!isEmpty(userId)) {
        return this.get('store').findRecord('user', userId).then((user) => {
          this.set('user', user);
          resolve();
        }, reject);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like that didn't solve it either. If it helps, Ember Inspector is showing that the user isn't being loaded into the user model. But to better understand how this is working it's sending the id that is being sent with the token and sending a GET to /users/:id?

Comment: @MattBrowning Yes, it's the way. You need to call `then` in `_loadCurrentUser` to trigger fetching user from backend. And for further check if `session.data.authenticated.user_id` has value or not